# Can an appservice act as a client when connecting to Azure Signalr?

Tags: azure, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I've got Azure Signalr set up and I've got an azure function which a client(browser) can connect to, start the negotiate endpoint and then connect directly to Azure Signalr to get updates.

Now, my question is, can a server/appservice(dotnetframework) also connect directly to Azure Signalr as a client and receive updates just like any browser would?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can act as a client if your application is hosted using appservice. You just need to make sure that you are using the SDK and listening for the messages being pushed.

Comment: I'm using dotnetframework are you able to point me to some sample that shows how to set it up?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet

Comment: how does the server listen to messages from signalr? eg. what is the server's equivalent to  `connection.on('chat', (data) => {
// run serverside code
            });`

Comment: what do you mean by server? you are just hosting your code on appservice

Comment: I've got an appservice that is the api. When I load the page in my browser, I connect to the api to get the Signalr url and auth token. I can then from my browser connect to Azure Signalr directly. Now, whenever Signalr pushes messages, my browser receives them, but I also want to receive them on my api server.